# Is there always a nontrivial tangent spherically symmetric vector field on an odd sphere?

Tags: geometry, vector-fields, spheres, symmetry

Let's look at an $n$-dimensional sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Let's consider a vector field $\vec{E}$ which is:

a. Tangent to the sphere.

b. Spherically symmetric (in the ambient space).

c. It is nontrivial: $\vec{E} \neq 0$ (somewhere).

By the [Hairy Ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), if $n$ is **even**, then $\vec{E}$ vanishes somewhere, and so by spherical symmetry it must vanish everywhere.

For $n=1$, there is such a field: $\vec{E}=a\hat{\theta}$.

Is is true that generally in the odd case we may find such a field? Or is there a condition on $n$?

Comment: By "spherically symmetric" do you mean invariant under the set of rotations (i.e., under the standard action of $SO(n + 1)$)? If so, the answer is no for $n > 1$: For any point $p$ at which $E_p \neq 0$, a nontrivial rotation around the line $\overline{0p}$ does not fix $E_p$.

Comment: @TravisWillse Yes, this is what I meant. You're right! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, "spherically symmetric" here means invariant under the set of rotations of $\Bbb R^{n + 1}$ (fixing $0$), i.e., the standard action of $SO(n + 1)$.

For $n > 1$ the answer is no: Pick a point $p$ at which the vector field $E$ does not vanish. Then, there is a nontrivial rotation that fixes $p$ but sends $E_p$ to $-E_p$, hence $E$ is not invariant. (For $n = 1$ the only rotation that fixes $p$ is the identity.)